# Value is never read - Static analyzer issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Value Stored to 'sort' is never read.

Below is the Sample Code:

```
NSString *sortLabel = @"View";

if([MManager sharedInstance].sortBy.count > 0)
{
    for (NSDictionary *sort in [MManager sharedInstance].sortBy) {
        if ([[sort objectForKey:@"selected"] intValue] == 1) {
            sortLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sort by: %@ ", [sort objectForKey:@"label"]];


        }
    }

}
else
{
    for (NSDictionary *sort in [MActions sharedInstance].sorts) {

        if ([[sort objectForKey:@"selected"] intValue] == 1) {
            sortLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", [sort objectForKey:@"label"]];

        }
    }
}

[self form:@"()" withText:[NSString stringWithString:sortLabel] andButton:self.sBtn];
```

Comment: what if you try this code NSString *sort = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"Sorting... %@", somecondition ? anotherXProperty : anotherYProperty]; [self someFunctionWithText:sort];

Comment: This is the sample code I have given here, but in my actual project there are many if -else condition which goes like this. And I need to solve this problem in that case.

Comment: why don't you create enum for all conditions and return text from there?

Comment: it looks like provided snapshot does not correspond to the code generated error, it is better to provide original.

Comment: Updated the code

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `@"dummyValue"` to `sort` but immediately changing it to something else.

Why not declare `sort` without assigning a value?

```
NSString *sort;

if(somecondition)
{
   sort = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"Sorting... %@",anotherXProperty];
}

else
{
  sort = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"Sorting... %@",anotherYProperty];
}

 [self someFunctionWithText:sort];
}
```

Comment: I tried this but the issue is still there. I am getting error for the statements inside if and else.

Comment: I think you will need to provide more code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You code you have posted does not give the error you mention.